# Jsoup getting different html compared to Firefox and other browsers

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm in trouble with some url's from a web-store called Kabum.

The url is http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/kabum3/produtos/descricao.cgi?id=01:02:23:55:159

If I enter the site in the address bar, or click the link, I got a page with the product, but If I use Jsoup, I get a page with only a meta refresh to the same address.

Tried setting the user agent, the referrer and follow the link in meta, but I got the same page.

My code is here:

```java
Document doc;
String url = "http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/kabum3/produtos/descricao.cgi?id=01:02:23:55:159";
try {
    String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0";
    String referrer = "http://www.google.com";
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20000).userAgent(ua).referrer(referrer).get();
    Elements meta = doc.select("html head meta");
    for (Iterator<Element> it = meta.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Element element = it.next();
        if (element.attr("http-equiv").matches("refresh")) {
            String novaUrl = element.attr("content").replaceFirst("\\d?;url=", "");
            System.out.printf("redirecting to %s%n", novaUrl);
            doc = Jsoup.connect(novaUrl).userAgent(ua).referrer(referrer).get();
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Teste1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return;
}
System.out.println(doc);
```

Comment: There appears to be a lot of javascript on that page. Have you taken that into account?

Comment: I don't need the javascript, only the html. The html returned in jsoup is only this (can't format this?):

    <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/kabum3/produtos/descricao.cgi?id=01:02:23:55:159" />
     </head>
     <body></body>
    </html>

Comment: But the javascript may be generating a lot of the web page that you are trying to extract and see. If so, you may be out of luck with jsoup.

Comment: Tried disabling javascript with noscript, but the page works well, so I think the problem isn't javascript

Comment: Hm, this has me stumped. I don't know why Jsoup isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-send a request with the cookies. The site is returning one session cookie which it expects to see in the next request.

```
String url = "http://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/kabum3/produtos/descricao.cgi?id=01:02:23:55:159";
Map<String, String> cookies = Jsoup.connect(url).execute().cookies();
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(cookies).get();
System.out.println(document.html());
```

Note that you should use the same cookies on every subsequent request you'd like to fire in the same session.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting.

Yeah, the following line: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=kabum.com.br/cgi-local/kabum3/produtos/…; />` is telling the browser to refresh the current url.

So it looks like the page tells the browser to keep refreshing the page until the server has satisfied whatever criteria it is looking for.

You'll have to figure out what criteria the server is looking for. The first things to check might be (1) the redirect limit that jsoup is set to (if it has "follow redirect" capability and can understand that `meta` tag), and (2) cookies.